# how to convert a particular array/list to a dictionary in a json structure

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I have the following json:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "object_k_id": "",
      "object_type": "schema",
      "object_meta": [
         {
            "source_id": 0,
            "database": "rawdwh",
            "schema": "abc"
         }

      ],
      "description": "A schema of all customer data",
      "business_name": "",
      "business_logic": "",
      "owners": [
         "xyz@gmail.com"
      ],
      "stewards": [
         "xyz@gmail.com"
      ],
      "verified_use_cases": "",
      "classifications": [],
      "domains": ""
   }
]
```

How do I remove only the object_meta 's [] because I want it as a dictionary rather than an array containing a dictionary. I am getting the above json as a result from a Dataframe by doing the following

```
def convert_to_json(item,df,final_columnnames,dict_meta):
    meta_obj = df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: x[dict_meta.get(item)].to_dict('records')).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'object_meta'})
    meta_obj_json = pandas.merge(df,meta_obj,how='inner',on='id')
    result_json=meta_obj_json[final_columnnames].to_json(orient='records')
    #print(type(result_json))
    final_json=json.dumps(json.loads(result_json), indent=3, sort_keys=False)
```

What the above code does is converts a particular Dataframe into a json format with the object_meta column being a super structure, like a dict of dict values, but then again the object_meta is of type list, but I want it to be jut a dict of dict as shown below

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "object_k_id": "",
      "object_type": "schema",
      "object_meta": 
         {
            "source_id": 0,
            "database": "raw data",
            "schema": "abc"
         }

      ,
      "description": "A schema of all customer data",
      "business_name": "",
      "business_logic": "",
      "owners": [
         ""
      ],
      "stewards": [
         "xyz@gmail.com"
      ],
      "verified_use_cases": "",
      "classifications": [],
      "domains": ""
   }
]
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:
this will take the first item in the "object_meta" value list and return it as the new value for the same key "object_meta"

```
json["object_meta"] = json["object_meta"][0]
```

Comment: Getting the below error

TypeError: string indices must be integers.
Also when I did the type(final_json) the result is a str

Comment: even though I used a json.dumps, it has returned a json str rather than a json object

Comment: use json.loads(final_json). json.loads will take a string of json data and convert it to a python dictionary

Comment: Tried this, didn't work dude

Comment: upload a snippet of your code showing the data and the way you are using json.loads()
json.loads() is definitely the method you are looking for